# Which method to avoid printing into log but still creating file in bash

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am new to working on sedona stuff, so I have tried following code.

```
sh("echo '{abData}'> abData.out")
```

It is supposed to create file called `abData.out` with the content of `abData` variable but it is also printing this content into logs and we don't want that. So I am looking for method to avoid printing logs, but it should create file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the built-in `writeFile` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) instead of shelling out to echo:

```
writeFile(file: 'abData.out', text: abData)
```